# f2py output is not updated

Tags: python, f2py

I tested `f2py` on ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7.

Here is a fortran source code.

C FILE: `FIB1.F`

```
  SUBROUTINE FIB(A,N)

  INTEGER N

  REAL*8 A(N)
  DO I=1,N
     IF (I.EQ.1) THEN
        A(I) = 0.0D0
     ELSEIF (I.EQ.2) THEN
        A(I) = 1.0D0
     ELSE 
        A(I) = A(I-1) + A(I-2)
     ENDIF
  ENDDO
  END
```

And the command for `f2py`:

```
f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1
```

And python script:

```
import numpy

import fib1

a = numpy.zeros(8,'d')

fib1.fib(a)

print a
```

Good. It is working.

I changed the fortran subroutine name, for example "FIB" -> "FIBC"

And again `f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1`.

But `fib1.so` is not updated.
It is working only `fib1.fib(a)`, not `fib1.fibc(a)`

How can I solve it?

Comment: your workflow works for me on OSX `10.10`, python `2.7.10`, f2py version 2 and numpy `1.10.0`